# Unfamiliar user agents 'CON 1.0 urlexists' and 'VANILLA 1.0 vanillastub' - are they malicious?

Tags: malware, wireshark

I'm analyzing a pcap via Wireshark, and there are multiple get requests to the IP. These requests use different user agents, which I can't find anything about when I search. The user agents:

```
CON 1.0 urlexists
VANILLA 1.0 vanillastub
```

Each get request they use a different range of bytes. Does it mean they are malicious?

Answer (score 2):

In many browsers using add-ons users can set agent to any value they want. Also applications can set this header to any value they want. That's why based on agent header it is impossible to say if this is a malicious request or not.

Comment: What about Java\1.5 and media type: application/x-msdos-program

Comment: @user232836: How is media type related to your question?

Comment: Not really, I thought I would help with my analysis

Comment: @user232836: An attacker will use what helps. If it helps to pretend to be a specific agent (browser type, browser version, OS) e.g. particular version of FireFox and particular version of Windows, hacker will set exactly this, no matter what he actually uses. If it helps to pretend to by mobile device or desktop device, he will set exactly this. It it helps to be some unknown agent, he will set this. If it helps to keep it empty, he will use empty agent. Agent header does not say anything about what the client actually is.

Answer (score 0):

This [VirusTotal Analysis](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/ecd64fcb1c8dd9f840faf8c3eda07807f0681aa43e19394b0c8f5cb6b88b5a9c/details) references `VanillaStub.exe`.

Upon reading the references from VirusTotal, I stumbled upon something called [VanillaRAT](https://github.com/DannyTheSloth/VanillaRAT). Perhaps the traffic you investigated was from a variant of VanillaRAT.

Comment: Please elaborate from which data/evidence you exactly got the idea it's actually `VanillaRAT`